# How to swap the first line with last line in a text file using SED/AWK

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am trying to swap the first line with last line in a text file in unix
file has:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

I want like this:

```
line6 
line2
line3
line4
line5
line1
```

I am using `sed -n -e '1 s/^.*$/$p' file` . Which is not happening.

Comment: I don't know the length of the file, meaning number of lines is not known, but need to replace the first line with last line of that file using sed/awk.

Comment: Try `first="$(head -n 1 file1)"; last="$(tail -n 1 file1)"; echo -e $"$last" "\n$(cat file1 | tail -n +2 | head -n -1)" $"\n$first" > file2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** As per Ed sir's comment adding this solution too here which will be more suitable in case 2nd line is empty then also it will work.

```
awk 'NR==1{first=$0;next} NR>2{val=val prev ORS} {prev=$0} END{print prev ORS val first}  Input_file
```

---

***EDIT:*** To exchange only first and last line following may help you(considering that your Input_file is same as shown sample).

```
awk 'FNR==1{first=$0;next} {val=(val?val ORS prev:prev?$0:"")} {prev=$0} END{print $0 ORS val ORS first}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
FNR==1{                            ##Checking if line is first line then do following.
  first=$0;                        ##Creating varable first whose value is current line value.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS prev:prev?$0:"")  ##Creating variable named val here whoe value is concatenating to its own value with variable prev value.
}
{
  prev=$0                          ##Creating variable prev whose value will be current value of line but will become previous value for next line.
}
END{
  print $0 ORS val ORS first       ##Printing current line ORS val ORS and first here.
}'  Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v from=1 -v to=6 'FNR==from{source=$0;next} FNR==to{target=$0;next} {val=val?val ORS $0:$0} END{print target ORS val ORS source}' Input_file
```

Comment: Sorry, the line numbers are not known, I just gave an example to line#6

Comment: @TobySpeight, sure will add explanation in few mins and let you know then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The last line has <EOF>, based on that we need to swap the first line. Thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh13   awk 'FNR==1{first=$0;next} {val=val?val ORS $0:$0} END{print $0 ORS val ORS first}'  worked for me.

Comment: @RaghavendraS, you could try to up-vote for people to encourage them and could select any of the answer as correct answer too, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Here is the result:

Comment: awk 'FNR==1{first=$0;next} {val=val?val ORS $0:$0} END{print $0 ORS val ORS first}' /tmp/abc.txt
line 6
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 1                                                                                                                  line6 is still listing and not replaced by line1.

Comment: @TobySpeight, sure sir added explanation now in my solution too.

Comment: Should I just give up and stop reminding you that an unparenthesized ternary expression will cause syntax errors in some contexts in some awks?  Also, the value of $0 in the END section is undefined behavior per POSIX so that will produce different output depending on the version of awk you're running - use prev instead of $0 in the END.

Comment: @EdMorton, I really apologies, I will try to fix it now :(

Comment: No problem. Your script will also fail if, say, line2 is empty (it'll delete line2 and line3 and duplicate line4). Really **think** about the logic. Not sure why the OP didn't of course... :-)

Comment: @EdMorton, changed it now, please bear with me, I am slow in learning I never meant to disobey you :(  I have changed it now and added note too that this will work as per user's sample(will try to add some conditions in it too)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 please don't take it that way, Im certainly not giving you orders or expecting you to obey me, I'm just trying to help you become a better awk script writer. Of course it's entirely up to you if you want my advice or not and if not just tell me to back off and I'll do so, no problem at all. I'm your peer, not your boss, I just have a bit more experience using awk, that's all.

Comment: @EdMorton, I always LOVE to get your advice please never leave it, but I am a slow learner :)

Comment: Well in that case... :-). Your one-liner contains different logic from your multi-line script in the ternary: `val=(val?val ORS prev:prev?$0:"")` vs `val=(val?val ORS prev:prev)`. The one-liner actually has a ternary within a ternary, which would be obvious if both ternaries were parenthesized in the following way: `val=(val?val ORS prev:(prev?$0:""))`

Comment: It'll still have bizarre output if line2 is empty and there's nothing in the question to indicate that line2 or any other line cannot be empty. It's also still using $0 instead of prev in the END. I also always worry when I see a variable (e.g. `val`) being tested on it's own to see if it's null what would happen if it had the value 0 rather than null and then you have to think about whether or not it can have the value 0.

Comment: FWIW here's how I'd write a script to do what you're trying to do: `awk 'NR==1{first=$0;next} NR>2{val=val prev ORS} {prev=$0} END{print prev ORS val first}'  file`

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks a TON Ed sir, I added your solution in post now, please do always correct me and guide me as always you do :)

Answer (score 2):

In sed, you'll need to make two passes; it probably makes more sense to use ed instead.  Then we just need two **m**ove commands - move the last line to just after line 1, then move the first line to the end:

```
$m1
1m$
```

### Demo

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

# Create our input file

file=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm "$file"' EXIT

cat >"$file" <<END
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
END

echo Before:
cat "$file"
echo

# Make the change

ed -s "$file"  <<<$'$m1\n1m$\nwq'

# Show the result

echo After:
cat "$file"
```

If you need to write a different output file, you can of course add a filename argument to the `wq` command, as usual.

Comment: @Downvoter: is this answer really so bad?  What should I change to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;s/\n\([^\n]*\)\(\n.*\n\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' file
```

Copy the whole file into the hold space (HS) and after the last line, swap to the HS, split the file into first line, middle and last line and substitute the first and last lines.

A two pass alternative solution:

```
sed -n '1s/.*/$c&/p;$s/.*/1c&/p' file | sed -f - file
```

Create a sed script to change the first line to the last and last line to the first.

Another solution using cat, head, tail and sed:

```
cat <(tail -1 file) <(sed '1d;$d' file) <(head -1 file)
```

Another sed solution:

```
sed -E '1h;1d;:a;N;$!ba;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\n\1/;G' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case a oneliner mixing, `head`, `tail`  and `sed`:

```
$ FIRST=$(head -1 file.txt) LAST=$(tail -1 file.txt) \
sed "1 s/^.*$/${LAST}/" file.txt | sed "$ s/^.*$/${FIRST}/"
```

Answer (score 0):

For very large files, you might be interested in a double pass:

```
awk '(NR!=FNR){print (FNR==1 ? t : (FNR==c ? h : $0) ); next }
     (NR==1){h=$0}{t=$0;c=NR}' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`sponge` util](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
f=file
{ tail -1 $f ; tail -n +2 $f | head -n -1 ; head -1 $f ; } | sponge $f
```